# Execution of shell stops after the first subshell

Tags: bash

mainshell.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
export subshell1="subshell1.sh"
export subshell2="subshell2.sh"
exec ./$subshell1
exec ./$subshell2
```

subshell1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "this is subshell 1"
```

subshell2.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "this is subshell 2"
```

But when I run mainshell.sh on Ubuntu 18.04, I get:

```
this is subshell 1
```

I looked around for a couple of hours on Stackooverflow for a couple of hours, but could not find any guidance, what I could find was mostly for running a single subshell. Any ideas?

Comment: `help exec`: _Replace the shell with the given command_. That means no further commands will be executed in the parent shell after calling `exec`

Comment: Why are you exporting the variables? Do you use the variables in the subshells?

Comment: Just use `./$subshell1` and `./$subshell2`, there's no need for `exec`.

Comment: Your scripts are misnamed.  If you invoke the script with `exec`, it is most definitely not a subshell.